# RXSearchView delay after typing

Tags: android

I have implemented SearchView widget and ContentProvider integration.

My concern is not to have the user spam the web service for every letter being typed or removed in the EditText of the SearchView. So the query of the ContentProvider should be triggered after user has stopped typing, say with a threshold of like 2 seconds.

I have not had luck doing this and I thought RXSearchView is the solution to that using debounce. However, even setting a 10 second delay does not to work. Am I on the right track? Or I need to use a different method/property.

```
int time = 10000;
RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView)
.delay(time, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.debounce(time, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.throttleWithTimeout(time, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.distinctUntilChanged()
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Comment: so use `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` and inside `onQueryTextChange` add some time related checks whether or not access your web service (using `Handler#postDelayed` for example)

Comment: hi pskink, i tried that approach using a Timer and a static variable in the ContentProvider class. After i finish typing, the variable will be set to true. However, the query() method already gets executed, so I call searchView.setQuery(query, false). I am not sure if that is an efficient approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I used and works fine:

1- First create a `Listener` for `setOnQueryTextChangedListener`:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener()...);
```

2- In your `onQueryTextChange` method call onNext of your subscriber:

```
                    @Override
                    public void onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                        subscriber.onNext(s);
                    }
```

3- Use [debounce](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html) method to emit:

```
               .filter(new Func1<String, Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public Boolean call(String s) {                //make sure query is not empty
                        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(s);
                    }
                })
                .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) //wait 500ms to 
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<TESTTTT>())
```

For complete code see [this](https://github.com/kmdupr33/iosched/blob/feature/rxjava_rewrite/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/SearchActivity.java) commit in iosched; Main part of the code is in `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

Comment: hi Amir, I tried this but the debounce does not work. I am using emulator to test it out so the typing is fast hence even a 5 second debounce has no effect. Every letter I typed, query() of ContentProvider gets triggered as well as subscriber.onNext() inside onQueryTextChange()